# Build: element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

We are transpiling our TypeScript 1.8 code forcing the software developer to set the types.

**Here are the error messages:**

- Description: Build: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
- Project myProject
- File: C:\dev\Scripts\machines.ts
- Lines: 77, 78, 80, 81, 96, 110, 111, 220
- Source: Build

**QUESTION**

How should we define the types of those variables?

- _matrixQuantityProduct
- _matrixQuantityLotSizeProduct
- matrixQuantityProduct2
- matrixQuantityLotSizeProduct2

**Source code**

```
    private _machines: Machine[];
    private _matrixQuantityProduct: Array<Array<number>>;
    private _matrixQuantityLotSizeProduct: Array<Array<number>>;
    private buildMatrixQuantity() {
        let matrixQuantityProduct : Array<Array<number>> = new Array();
        let matrixQuantityLotSizeProduct: Array<Array<number>> = new Array();

        // on cree le array 2D et les clés dynamiques
        for (let i = 0; i < this._machines.length; i++) {
            let matrixQuantityProduct2 : Array<any> = [];
            let matrixQuantityLotSizeProduct2: Array<any>  = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < this._machines.length; j++) {
                    matrixQuantityProduct2[this._machines[j].code] = 0; [line 77]
                matrixQuantityLotSizeProduct2[this._machines[j].code] = 0; [line 78]
            }
            matrixQuantityProduct[this._machines[i].code] = matrixQuantityProduct2; [line 80]
            matrixQuantityLotSizeProduct[this._machines[i].code] = matrixQuantityLotSizeProduct2; [line 80]
        }

        this.listMatrixLog(matrixQuantityProduct, matrixQuantityLotSizeProduct);

        let _productCodeElements: Element[] = this._productModel.getProducts();
        for (let i = 0; i < _productCodeElements.length; i++) {
            let _quantityProduct: number = this._productModel.getQuantityProduct(_productCodeElements[i].nodeValue);
            let _processCodeElements: Element[] = this._productModel.getProcessProduct(_productCodeElements[i].nodeValue);
            for (let j = 0; j < _processCodeElements.length; j++) {

                let _lotSizeOperation: Element[] = this._productModel.getLotSizeOperation(_productCodeElements[i].nodeValue, _processCodeElements[j].nodeValue);
                let _machinesRefElements: Element[] = this._productModel.getResourceMachineProcess(_processCodeElements[j].nodeValue);
                for (let k = 0; k < _machinesRefElements.length - 1; k++) {

                    matrixQuantityProduct[_machinesRefElements[k].nodeValue][_machinesRefElements[k + 1].nodeValue] += _quantityProduct; [line 96]
                    //matrixQuantityLotSizeProduct[][] += (_quantityProduct /parseInt(_lotSizeOperation[k].nodeValue)) ;

                }
            }
        }
        this.listMatrixLog(matrixQuantityProduct, matrixQuantityLotSizeProduct);

        this._matrixQuantityProduct = matrixQuantityProduct;
    }

    private listMatrixLog(matrixQuantityProduct: Array<Array<number>>, matrixQuantityLotSizeProduct: Array<Array<number>>) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this._machines.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < this._machines.length; j++) {
                this._log.trace("Machine/listMatrix - Quantity Matrixf : " + matrixQuantityProduct[this._machines[i].code][this._machines[j].code]); [line 110]
                this._log.trace("matrice quantityLotSize indice i = " + this._machines[i].code + " indice j = " + this._machines[j].code + " ,contient: " + matrixQuantityLotSizeProduct[this._machines[i].code][this._machines[j].code]); [line 111]
            }
        }
    }


    let cylinder = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateCylinder("cylinder", distance, this._matrixQuantityProduct[machineA][machineB] / 50, this._matrixQuantityProduct[machineA][machineB] / 50, 36, 1, this._scene, true); [line 220]
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like you have some logical problems inside your code. Assuming that `code` property is of type string, the following lines does not play nice together:

```
let matrixQuantityProduct2: Array<any> = [];
matrixQuantityProduct2[this._machines[j].code] = 0;
```

Lets say `this._machines[j].code` evaluates to '123'.

So you define variable of type array and try to access its element by string key '123'. In such case you will get value of the property `123` on `matrixQuantityProduct2` object. That is probably not there - its an array after all?

Most likely you would like to use `matrixQuantityProduct2` as a dictionary. In such case you can have it like this:

```
interface INameToValueMap
{
    [key: string]: any;
}

let matrixQuantityProduct3: INameToValueMap = {};
matrixQuantityProduct3["123"] = 0;
```

Note initialization with `{}` instead of `[]`.

As a side note. You can disable such errors by setting `"noImplicitAny": false` in your tsconfig.json `compilerOptions` section. But I would not recommend doing this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

About line 96, "nodeValue" seems to return type string, so try to use parseInt() in order to change it to a number.

```
matrixQuantityProduct[parseInt(_machinesRefElements[k].nodeValue)][parseInt(_machinesRefElements[k + 1].nodeValue)] += _quantityProduct;
```

About the others, I do not get any errors by just trying your code, but it might be that you are creating `Array<any>` and trying to save it into `Array<Array<number>>`